# Infinite scroll problems with get value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, scroll

I am trying to make infinite scrolling script. It works fine on index.php page..but when I try to sort my items on the page,thats where everything goes wrong..

Code:

```
$limit = 10; 

$page = (int) (!isset($_GET['p'])) ? 1 : $_GET['p'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM items";

$start = ($page * $limit) - $limit;

if( mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)) > ($page * $limit) ){
    $next = ++$page;
}
$query = mysql_query("{$sql} where sold = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");

if(isset($_GET["price_lth"])){
    $query  = mysql_query("{$sql} where sold = 0 ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");
}
if(isset($_GET["price_htl"])){
    $query  = mysql_query("{$sql} where sold = 0 ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit} ");
}
if(isset($_GET["sold"])){
    $query  = mysql_query("{$sql} where sold = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");
}
```

When I am trying to sort my items it goes like this : www.sample.com/?sold and when I scroll  my page down javascript adds www.sample.com/?sold#/page/2 and then 2 items are fethed and added to the sold ones but these 2 items are first 2 from the db (not the ones marked as sold,it seems that js grabs first 2 records from the db). There are 14 records in total in my db.. Any suggestions why the sort function doesnt work? Because if I edit line like this (changed sold = 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("{$sql} where sold = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");
```

It works ok on the index page,because there are only 2 items on db which are sold. So no other items are fetched from db apart these 2 ones.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: have you checked that your page variables is getting set correctly?

Comment: It does it shows on that page only 2 items which are sold, but when I scroll down it adds another 2 not sold ones.